# Rails: Creating Wrong Table Name With a Namespaced STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, namespaces, sti

I have a model which uses STI:

```
class Contributor::Name < Contributor::NameBase
  ...
end
```

From this model:

```
class Contributor::NameBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Whenever `Contributor::Name` gets instantiated, I receive this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'shelflives_development.contributor_basis_name_bases' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `contributor_basis_name_bases`
```

It seems that instead of looking up the table `contributor_name_bases`, ActiveRecord is looking up `contributor_basis_name_bases`. Why is adding `basis` between `contributor` and `name_bases`? How can I get it to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's not a answer about why rails is adding '`basis`' but it will work for you.
Use `set_table_name 'contributor_name_bases'` in your model.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick! Hope somebody comes along with an explanation at some point, but for now, knowing about `set_table_name` will allow to deal with this and similar problems.